# Does Chromecast require internet access?

Tags: chromecast

Does Google Chromecast require internet access to either,

- cast an android screen
- cast use something like [Videostream for Google Chromecast™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/videostream-for-google-ch/cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl?hl=en), or VLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can *not* connect Chromecast to an AP without Internet Access, it has to have [some way to communicate with Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/Chromecast/XRktmNTk0QY)

- to send your private information

  - when you accidentally permit it
  - or, when the NSA otherwise asks politely for it.
- to update the background pictures when it is in idle mode.

Neither of those local features should require it, but they do.

Comment: NSA haha ---that was a good one

Comment: @TejasShetty DON'T FORGET TO LIKE AND SUBSCRIBE.